# Как получить разницу во времени

Tags: python, datetime

В базе данных хранится время начала проката самоката, допустим 12:00. В 12:45 самокат был сдан и нужно посчитать сумму, где одна минута равна к примеру 10 руб.

Так я записываю начало проката:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
greatest_orm.new_bike(bicycle_id, now.strftime('%H:%M'))
```

В конце я получаю строку из базы данных где я и застрял, как из неё сделать объект чтобы вывести разницу и тем более посчитать поминутно сумму я не знаю, либо же стоит вообще поменять реализацию.

UPD: При попытке привести сторку к объекту datetime получается бред

```
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime('12:40', '%H:%M')
date_time_ob2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('13:24', '%H:%M')

time_delta = (date_time_obj - date_time_ob2)
print(time_delta)

>>> -1 day, 23:16:00
```

Comment: покажите код `.new_bike`

Comment: Приведите время из базы данных к `datetime`, возьмите текущую датувремя и вычтите из нее время из базы данных, получите объект `timedelta`, у него есть метод `total_seconds`, разделите его `60` получите количеством минут. Я бы хранил время взятия самоката полностью - так видно и дату и время, плюс с этим удобнее работать. Да и если я возьму самокат на сутки, то могу ничего не заплатить? :)

Comment: @gil9red обновил вопрос. Для того заведения что дают на прокат самокаты, нельзя на сутки взять самокат)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вычитать нужно из большей даты

```
import datetime

date_time_obj1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('12:40', '%H:%M')
date_time_obj2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('13:24', '%H:%M')

time_delta = date_time_obj2 - date_time_obj1
print(time_delta)
# 0:44:00

seconds = time_delta.total_seconds()
print(seconds)
# 2640.0

print(seconds // 60)
# 44.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо наоборот отнимать. Первое время из второго, а не второе из первого.

Comment: Да, учёл. Не понимаю как не заметил